# $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+' .js ul').slideToggle(120)

Tags: jquery, optimization

Is there a way to optimize this jquery line

```
$('#'+$(this).attr('id')+' .js ul').slideToggle(120)
```

just referring to $(this), and not retrieving the id of the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find off of the element you already have.

```
$(this).find('.js ul').slideToggle(120);
```

Also for future note.  You don't have to do `$(this).attr('id');`.  You can simply do `this.id`.  It is an existing Element property.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanx!

Comment: Just for grins, you can also do `$(this)[0].id` though it would be more practically used like `$('.some-selector')[0].id` :)

Comment: Sure, but the point I was getting at is you don't need the overhead of creating a jQuery object to get the id property.